# The Componentwise Convergence Criterion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> [image]

Can someone explain to me what does it mean for a sequence of points to converge componentwise. Provide an example thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $p_i$ is the projection onto the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For example, in dimension $n=2$, the sequence whose $k^{\text{th}}$ element is the point $\mathbf{u}_k = (1/k^2, (1+k)/k)$ converges to the point $(0, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, since the first component converges to
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} p_1(\mathbf u_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = 0$$
and the second component converges to
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} p_2(\mathbf u_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1+k}{k} = 1$$.